# C# MVC Post method on bootstrap dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, controller, html.beginform

On a bootstrap drop down list I want it to do a post to a different action result. I tried using the Html Begin Form to do a post but it didnt work. See code below.

Before:

```
<div class="OrderButton btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Place Order <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Order One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Order Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Attempt:

```
<div class="OrderButton btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Place Order <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Home", "OrderOne", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <li><a>Order One</a></li>
        }
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Home", "OrderTwo", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <li><a>Order Two</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ActionLink` here.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">            
            <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Order One", "OrderOne","Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST"})</li>   
            <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Order Two", "OrderTwo","Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST"})</li>            
    </ul>
```

Comment: how about the list button display name? Where does that go

Comment: You can see that we can add link text in ActionLink method. here first parameter is link text so it will be displayed as display name

Comment: Thanks but I used the @html.ActionLink instead of Ajax